# Invoking non-blocking operations sequentially while consuming from a Flux including retries

Tags: java, apache-kafka, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

So my use-case is to consume messages from Kafka in a Spring Webflux application while programming in the reactive style using Project Reactor, and to perform a non-blocking operation for each message in the same order as the messages were received from Kafka. The system should also be able to recover on its own.

Here is the code snippet that is setup to consume from :

```
    Flux<ReceiverRecord<Integer, DataDocument>> messages = Flux.defer(() -> {
        KafkaReceiver<Integer, DataDocument> receiver = KafkaReceiver.create(options);
        return receiver.receive();
    });

    messages.map(this::transformToOutputFormat)
            .map(this::performAction)
            .flatMapSequential(receiverRecordMono -> receiverRecordMono)
            .doOnNext(record -> record.receiverOffset().acknowledge())
            .doOnError(error -> logger.error("Error receiving record", error))
            .retryBackoff(100, Duration.ofSeconds(5), Duration.ofMinutes(5))
            .subscribe();
```

As you can see, what I do is: take the message from Kafka, transform it into an object intended for a new destination, then send it to the destination, and then acknowledge the offset to mark the message as consumed and processed. It is critical to acknowledge the offset in the same order as the messages being consumed from Kafka so that we don't move the offset beyond messages that were not fully processed (including sending some data to the destination). Hence I'm using a `flatMapSequential` to ensure this.

For simplicity let's assume the `transformToOutputFormat()` method is an identity transform.

```
public ReceiverRecord<Integer, DataDocument> transformToOutputFormat(ReceiverRecord<Integer, DataDocument> record) {
    return record;
}
```

The `performAction()` method needs to do something over the network, say call an HTTP REST API. So the appropriate APIs return a Mono, which means the chain needs to be subscribed to. Also, I need the `ReceiverRecord` to be returned by this method so that the offset can be acknowledged in the flatMapSequential() operator above. Because I need the Mono subscribed to, I'm using `flatMapSequential` above. If not, I could have used a `map` instead.

```
public Mono<ReceiverRecord<Integer, DataDocument>> performAction(ReceiverRecord<Integer, DataDocument> record) {
    return Mono.just(record)
            .flatMap(receiverRecord ->
                    HttpClient.create()
                            .port(3000)
                            .get()
                            .uri("/makeCall?data=" + receiverRecord.value().getData())
                            .responseContent()
                            .aggregate()
                            .asString()
            )
            .retryBackoff(100, Duration.ofSeconds(5), Duration.ofMinutes(5))
            .then(Mono.just(record));
```

I have two conflicting needs in this method:
1. Subscribe to the chain that makes the HTTP call
2. Return the ReceiverRecord

Using a flatMap() means my return type changes to a Mono. Using doOnNext() in the same place would retain the ReceiverRecord in the chain, but would not allow the HttpClient response to be subscribed to automatically.

I can't add `.subscribe()` after `asString()`, because I want to wait till the HTTP response is completely received before the offset is acknowledged.

I can't use `.block()` either since it runs on a parallel thread.

As a result, I need to cheat and return the `record` object from the method scope.

The other thing is that on a retry inside `performAction` it switches threads. Since flatMapSequential() eagerly subscribes to each Mono in the outer flux, this means that while acknowledgement of offsets can be guaranteed in order, we can't guarantee that the HTTP call in `performAction` will be performed in the same order.

So I have two questions.

1. Is it possible to return `record` in a natural way rather than returning the method scope object?
2. Is it possible to ensure that both the HTTP call as well as the offset acknowledgement are performed in the same order as the messages for which these operations are occurring?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the solution I have come up with.

```
Flux<ReceiverRecord<Integer, DataDocument>> messages = Flux.defer(() -> {
    KafkaReceiver<Integer, DataDocument> receiver = KafkaReceiver.create(options);
    return receiver.receive();
});

messages.map(this::transformToOutputFormat)
        .delayUntil(this::performAction)
        .doOnNext(record -> record.receiverOffset().acknowledge())
        .doOnError(error -> logger.error("Error receiving record", error))
        .retryBackoff(100, Duration.ofSeconds(5), Duration.ofMinutes(5))
        .subscribe();
```

Instead of using flatMapSequential to subscribe to the performAction Mono and preserve sequence, what I've done instead is delayed the request for more messages from the Kafka receiver until the action is performed. This enables the one-at-a-time processing that I need.

As a result, performAction doesn't need to return a Mono of ReceiverRecord. I also simplified it to the following:

```
public Mono<String> performAction(ReceiverRecord<Integer, DataDocument> record) {
    HttpClient.create()
        .port(3000)
        .get()
        .uri("/makeCall?data=" + receiverRecord.value().getData())
        .responseContent()
        .aggregate()
        .asString()
        .retryBackoff(100, Duration.ofSeconds(5), Duration.ofMinutes(5));
}
```